# How do critical hits on companions work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Can [companions](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/companion) on demon hunters like the bat land critical hits, and do they count on the passive "[Night Stalker](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/night-stalker)" to receive discipline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your companions are able to land critical hits, and their critical hit chance appears to be inherited from the player (including Sharpshooter).

However these critical hits do not appear to trigger the effects of the Night Stalker passive.